# "Optional" WHERE clause on (My)SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, where-clause

I'm having a bit of a problem with a SELECT query in MySQL and I'd be thankful for some pointers. Please feel free to point me towards an existing answer (if there is one and I missed it).

The query is currently as follows:

```
SELECT e.*, ie.aaa, ue.bbb, ue.ccc
FROM ie
LEFT JOIN e ON ie.e_id = e.e_id
LEFT JOIN ue ON ie.e_id = ue.e_id
WHERE ie.other_id = ? AND ue.unrelated_id = ?
ORDER BY ...
```

There are three tables: **ie**, **e** and **ue**.

Tables **ie** and **ue** are relationships of **e**, and therefore contain foreign keys to it (e_id). **?** represents an input parameter.

The problem is the **ue.unrelated_id = ?** part. What I'm *really* trying to do here is:

- To return ue.ccc if and only if there is a ue relationship for unrelated_id = ?. If it doesn't exist, I want this field to be null.
- Even if the ue relationship for unrelated_id = ? doesn't exist, this query should always return the remaining fields (ie is guaranteed to exist for other_id = ?).

Unfortunately, if I remove this where clause, I get ue.ccc for a "random" unrelated_id. But if I keep it, the query won't return any results at all if ue doesn't exist for this unrelated_id! I also tried adding OR ue.unrelated_id IS NOT NULL, but this makes the query return no results if the ue table is empty.

Any ideas? Please drop a comment if you need further clarification. I should answer quickly in the next few hours.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do one of two things:

```
SELECT e.*, ie.aaa, ue.bbb, ue.ccc
FROM ie
LEFT JOIN e ON ie.e_id = e.e_id
LEFT JOIN ue ON ie.e_id = ue.e_id AND ue.unrelated_id = ?
WHERE ie.other_id = ? 
ORDER BY ...
```

Or

```
SELECT e.*, ie.aaa, ue.bbb, ue.ccc
FROM ie
LEFT JOIN e ON ie.e_id = e.e_id
LEFT JOIN ue ON ie.e_id = ue.e_id
WHERE ie.other_id = ? AND (ue.unrelated_id IS NULL OR ue.unrelated_id = ?)
ORDER BY ...
```

I would go with the first query, however.

EDIT: Please note that the 2nd query is only approperiate if `ue.unrelated_id` is not a nullable column.

Comment: Perfect! I did not know that syntax existed. Thanks! (Went with query 1)

Comment: Do u have any idea please how to add an optional clause IN , thank you

Comment: So, this `?` symbol need any condition? Because i can't just use it like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = ?` right?

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal the `?` is typically used as a placeholder when using a "prepared statement" for MySQL, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html.  If you're just reading it, however, you can replace it with a verbatim value instead of `?`.

Comment: @Matthew Ok, so basically the `?` sign can work only on "prepared statements" right? The OP should have mention it a bit above, since not everyone understands this.. Thanks bytheway

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal prepared statements are fairly ubiquitous for all flavours of SQL.  If this is a new topic, you should probably read up on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection